# Create a confirmation popup within the area of particular image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple images on my page which are getting created dynamically within a div when user upload the images. Each image is having its unique parent div. When user wants to delete an image, I want a delete confirmation within the limits of that particular div only (not over full body) which currently I am unable to achieve. Currently I do have like this -  [image].

where as I want to show this pop up message only over that particular image, something like this -  [image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using JavaScript we can achieve it.

```
 HTML Structure
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="/image.png">
            <span class="edit" onclick="myFunction();">edit</span>
           <div class="popup-option"></div> 
        </div>

JavaScript function 
       function  myFunction(id){
        var htm = "<div class='popup'>"+
                  "<button>Delete</button>"+
                  "<button>Cancel</button>"+
                  "</div>";
           $('.popup-option').append(htm);    

       }

    CSS
    .img-wrapper{  /* make main wrapper position relative and add your style */
       position: relative;
     }
    .popup{ /* popup will cover full width of that particular item*/
     position : absolute;
     left: 0;
     right:0;
     width :100%;
     height:100%;
     z-index: 999;
     background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like

```
function getPosition(element) {
var xPosition = 0;
var yPosition = 0;

while(element) {
    xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
    yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
    element = element.offsetParent;
}
return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
```

To get the position of the image then show the pop up in the same coords